# StackQueue Amortized Time Implementation

Tags: performance, data-structures, queue

According to the specifications in quotes below, a queue is implemented (the language is in Ruby, but hopefully it reads okay to everyone).

> Implement a queue using stacks. That is, write enqueue and dequeue
>   using only push and pop operations.
>
> In terms of performance, enqueue should be O(1), but dequeue may be
>   worst-case O(n). In terms of ammortized time, dequeue should be O(1).
>   Prove that your solution accomplishes this.

```
class StackQueue
  def initialize
    @in, @out = [], []
  end

  def enqueue(value)
    @in << value
  end

  def dequeue
    if @out.empty?
      @out << @in.pop until @in.empty?
    end

    @out.pop
  end
end
```

I'm wondering, how would you prove the amortized time for the dequeue?
Thanks!

Comment: Obvious answer to #1: `shift` is not in the set of methods allowed by the specification, which are just `push` and `pop`.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively the O(1) amortised complexity is easily understood: every element we dequeue is pushed onto `in` exactly once, popped from `in` exactly once, pushed onto `out` exactly once and popped from `out` exactly once, all of which are O(1) operations.

It is easily proven using the potential method. Every time we `enqueue` a value, we "pay" 3: 1 for the cost of the `push`, 2 we save for future moving to `out`.

We can also pay for dequeue with 3: 1 for the `empty` test, 1 for the `pop` on `out`, 1 for determining `in` is empty. We can pay for every `pop` on `in` and `push` on `out` with the savings from our surplus in `enqueue`.

We can afford all operations by "paying" 3 for each, giving an amortised complexity of O(1).